# Hover effect not reaching the ends of webpage

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made a Boostrap Menu bar, when you collapse the browser to small it comes up,I put hover effects over the buttons but they don't completely touch the sides of the browser, how do I get it to reach the ends?

https://bluemints000.github.io/

https://github.com/BlueMints000/BlueMints000.github.io

Comment: Can you please post the related codes in your question? Also, try not to use an ancient version of Bootstrap and please use lowercases for your folder names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how it is with bootstrap and its quite normal. If you inspect element and click on the dive with class:navbar-collapse collapse in you will see that there are some padding lefft and padding right in there that makes it not touch the sides.

```
<div id="collapsable-nav" class="navbar-collapse collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">

    <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="visible-xs text-center"></li>
    <li class="visible-xs text-center"><a href="#">Chicken</a></li>
    <li class="visible-xs text-center"><a href="#">Beef</a></li>
    <li class="visible-xs text-center"><a href="#">Sushi</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.container-fluid>.navbar-collapse, .container-fluid>.navbar-header, .container>.navbar-collapse, .container>.navbar-header {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.collapse.in {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    overflow-x: visible;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgb(255 255 255 / 10%);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgb(255 255 255 / 10%);
}
```

Comment: Never override Bootstrap CSS classes, especially for margin and padding, as it will break the grid system.

Comment: Yeah Bootstrap is great for having it's own sizes! lol. Right now with the project that I'm working on, I need to use an older version of Bootstrap. I can't use Bootstrap 5 right now. I will post the code next time, ok. There's got to be a way to override the hover.

Comment: isnt it the width not reaching the ends that was your problem? you are talking about hover now, which is the actual problem you want to solve?@Raptor